# multi_index hashed unique optional parameter

Tags: c++, multi-index

I have a multi_index with multiple hashed_unique indixes Indexes(A,B,C).
Not all insertion to hash contain information for all indexes. Some of the indexes may be empty. And some may contain all entries.
I defined them hashed_unique because if it's not empty, it is unique.
I could define it as hashed_non_unique and put each key in a wrapper that tell if key is empty as proposed in [Boost Multi_Index Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485922/boost-multi-index-question?rq=1)
 
But then i will need to search for each key, before trying to insert/modify/replace to avoid a case of non_unique keys, which is not good performance solution.
Is there a better solution?
If i defined all indexes as hashed_unique it won't accept insertion of more than one empty value per index.

For example:

```
(11,6,8)
(10,3,empty)
(empty,4,empty)
(empty,empty,1)
```

I'm using boost 1.49 and the multi index is in shared memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following wrapper:

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/functional/hash.hpp>

template<typename T>
class maybe
{
public:
  maybe():impl(boost::make_shared<int>(0)){}
  maybe(const T& t):impl(t){}

  bool empty()const{return impl.which()==0;}
  T& get(){return boost::get<T>(impl);}
  const T& get()const{return boost::get<T>(impl);}

  friend bool operator==(const maybe& x,const maybe& y){return x.impl==y.impl;}
  friend std::size_t hash_value(const maybe& x){return boost::hash<impl_type>()(x.impl);}

private:
  typedef boost::variant<boost::shared_ptr<void>,T> impl_type;

  impl_type impl;
};

...

maybe<int> x=5;
maybe<int> y;  // empty
maybe<int> z;  // empty
```

The nice thing about `maybe` is that empty values are different (that, is, `!(y==z)` in the example), so you can keep your Boost.MultiIndex indices unique.

Comment: Thanks, i will try this. I'm using it in shared memory. Is variant safe to be used in shared memory? I will use boost::interprocess::shared_ptr.

Comment: Good question. Boost.Variant uses heap space (which is not shared memory friendly) but only as a temporary backup except in corner cases: www.boost.org/doc/html/variant/design.html#variant.design.never-empty.problem . In your particular situation (both `int` and `shared_ptr` don't throw on copy) I think you're safe.

Comment: @joaquin-m-lopez-munozin I have a problem using shared_ptr in shared memory, because i need to give it a name in the construct function of the managed shared_mem and then it is the same name for all entries, so the same entry. Am i correct?

Comment: i just saw the anonymous_instance option

Comment: I have the following error, i'm looking at it now. static boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::block_header<size_type>* boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::block_header<size_type>::block_header_from_value(const void*, size_t, size_t) [with size_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion `hdr->m_value_alignment == algn' failed.

Comment: @joaquin-m-lopez-munozin  i still have the error. The code is at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/722a32ba8a7ce4ad It occurs in destructor. The code i put in the link run in my computer, but not in coliru ( maybe because of the patch you gave me)